# How to I enable jumbo frames on just one network interface?

Tags: 11.10, networking

I have a server with a storage network which currently supports jumbo frames.

I want to enable just eth1 to have that ability.  What settings do I change and what is the best way to test the configuration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The question is phrased like there's a way to globally turn it on. I'm not aware of that method, here's how I'd turn it on:

```
sudo ip link set eth1 mtu 9000
```

Or (as this is a server) if you're using the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration, you can simply stick it in at the end like so:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address ...
        netmask ...
        network ...
        broadcast ...
        gateway ...
        dns-nameservers ...
        mtu 9000
```

I suggest you test the MTU rate with `ip` *before* you persist it in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Oh and you'll need to run `sudo service networking restart` if you only used the second method there.

You can verify the configuration with `ip`:

```
ip link show eth1
```

And there are various things like `traceroute --mtu` that can measure and test that MTU.